# Behavior of holomorphic functions on the boundary of the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

$\textbf{Problem.}$ Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. Show there are points $a_n\in \mathbb{D}$, $a\in \partial \mathbb{D}$, and $b\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $a_n\to a$ and $f(a_n)\to b$, as $n\to \infty.$

$\textbf{Attempt at a Solution:}$
First, if $f$ has an essential singularity at some point $a\in \partial\mathbb{D}$, I think the statement follows easily.

To contradiction suppose that the statement is false. That is, suppose that $f(a_n)\to \infty$ for all sequences $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbb{D}$ where $a_n\to a$, $a\in \partial\mathbb{D}.$

Then $$\frac{1}{f(z)}\to 0, \hspace{1cm} \mbox{as} \hspace{1cm}|z|\to 1.$$

$\textbf{ Case 1}$: If $f$ is nowhere vanishing on $\mathbb{D}$, then $1/f(z)$ would be holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and can be extended continuously on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. Then, by the maximum principle this would imply that $1/f(z)\equiv 0$ on all of $\mathbb{D}$. But this contradicts the fact that $f$ is holomorphic (non-constant) in $\mathbb{D}.$

$\textbf{Case 2}$: Suppose $f$ has a finite number of zeros in $\mathbb{D}$. That is, let $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ be points of $\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(b_i)=0.$

Let $r=\min \{|z-b_i| \forall z\in \partial\mathbb{D}\}$, and consider the annulus $$A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: r<r_1<|z|<1\}$$

Then, $1/f(z)$ is holomorphic on $A$, and can be continuously extended to $\bar A$. (Note that, $1/f(z)$ is already holomorphic for $|z|=r_1$.

Let $$g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}\frac{1}{f(r_1/z)}.$$ Then $g(z)=0$ for all $z\in \partial \bar{A}$. By the maximum principle it follows that $g(z)\equiv 0$ on $A$, and by the identity theorem it follows that $1/f(z)\equiv 0$ on $A$. But this, again, contradicts the fact that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and thus on $A$ as well.

$\textbf{Case 3:}$ This is the case where i'm not so sure what i'm doing is correct.

Suppose, now, that $f$ has an infinite number of zeros in $\mathbb{D}$. That is, let $E=\{b_i\in \mathbb{D}: g(b_i)=0\}$. Then, $E$ cannot have an accumulation point in $\mathbb{D}.$

My idea was to take neighborhoods, $\mathbb{B}_{r_i}(b_i)$, and consider $$g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}\prod_{w\in A_w}\frac{1}{f(z/w)},$$ where $A_w=\{w\in \mathbb{D}: |w-b_i|=r_i\},$ for all $z\in \overline{\mathbb{D}\setminus\bigcup \mathbb{B}_{r_i}(b_i)}.$

Then, I would argue similarly as in Case 2.

There is probably a much shorter method.

I'd appreciate any thoughts or suggestions!!

Comment: I don't know if I misunderstood ( misunderestimated?) , but isn't this a case of sequential continuity? I mean, let $f(a)=b$. Then $a_n \rightarrow a$ would imply $f(a_n) \rightarrow f(a)=b$. Did I misread?

Comment: We don't know whether $f$ has a continuous extension to the boundary of $\mathbb{D}.$

Comment: The classification "essential singularity", "pole", or "removable singularity" applies only to isolated singularities.  If we only know that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb D$, then the points on $\partial \mathbb D$ are not necessarily going to be isolated singularities.  So it seems to me that your proof starts incorrectly.

Comment: That is correct, that's not quite what I intended either, since I don't use that anywhere in my proof. I will erase that part. I only used the fact that $1/f(z)\to 0$ as $|z|\to 1.$ Someone else pointed out that as well. Thanks for taking the time to read my solution though!!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: I am a little confused about my solution now. Specifically, the part I say "To Contradiction". What's confusing me is the fact that there might be other ways for that limit not to exist, and not just for $f(a_n)\to \infty$. Any ideas how to resolve this issue??

Comment: @V-B Suppose you can find a sequence $a_n \in \mathbb D$ such that the sequence $f(a_n)$ does not converge to infinity.  Then there must exist an $R>0$ such that $|f(a_n)| \le R$ for infinitely many $n$.  But the ball of radius $R$ is compact, and hence there must be a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Thanks! I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 3):

> This implies that $f$ has a pole at each point of $\partial\mathbb{D}$.

That is inaccurate, a pole is by definition an isolated singularity.

That doesn't affect the argument, though.

Note that case 3. cannot occur. If $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $\mathbb{D}$, since the zeros cannot have an accumulation point in $\mathbb{D}$ without $f$ being identically $0$, you have a seuqence $(z_k)$ of points in $\mathbb{D}$ converging to a boundary point $z_\ast$ with $f(z_k) = 0$ for all $k$, hence $f(z_k) \to 0$.

To shorten the argument further, treat cases 1. and 2. together, consider

$$g(z) = \frac{\prod(z-z_k)^{n_k}}{f(z)},$$

where the $z_k$ are the finitely many zeros of $f$ in $\mathbb{D}$ (possibly none) with multiplicities $n_k$. Then you still have $g(z) \to 0$ for $z\to \partial \mathbb{D}$, hence $g \equiv 0$, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure how to phrase this part. Because all I really needed and used in my proof was the fact that $1/f(z)\to 0$ as $|z|\to 1.$

Comment: I like your suggested method. Works as a charm :) However, is there anything wrong with my argument in Cases 1 and 2? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, well, not with the argument as such. You have a typo in case 2. You wrote $f(z/r_1)$, but it should be $f(r_1/z)$. But I'm sure that is indeed just a typo, the argument is correct.

Comment: Yes, absolutely!!! That doesn't make much sense as it is. I'll correct it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am just a beginning complex analysis. Don't we need some additional hypotheses for this question? If not, isn't $f(z)=z$ for example an easy counterexample?

Comment: @Ovi No, you have mis-parsed the assertion (because it is formulated in an unexpected way). It doesn't say that for every $b \in \mathbb{C}$ there is a sequence etc., it says "there is a $b \in \mathbb{C}$ and a sequence …". A more expected formulation of the assertion is that we cannot have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert f(a_n)\rvert = +\infty$ for every sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{D}$ with $\lvert a_n\rvert \to 1$. Or more concisely, we cannot have $\lim_{z \to \partial\mathbb{D}} \lvert f(z)\rvert = +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand the question, in Case 3 you pick $a_i = b_i,$ and $b=0.$ Notice that the zeros of $f$ cannot have an accumulation points in the interior, they must have an accumulation point on the boundary.

Comment: I think I mentioned that $E$ cannot have an accumulation point in $\mathbb{D}$. In any case, I think you are correct!!! The infinite sequence of the zeros of $f$ already gives us the desired result :) Do you see any flaws in the other two cases?

Comment: Looks good to me...