# holomorphic functions and boundedness at the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a bounded region $U=\{z:|z|<1\}.$ Show that there is a sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $U$ such that $|z_n|\rightarrow 1$ and $\{f(z_n)\}$ is bounded.

How can I approach this problem, without any continuity condition at the boundary?

Comment: Start by supposing the claim were wrong. What can you then deduce?

Comment: You can find a nice answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620881/behavior-of-holomorphic-functions-on-the-boundary-of-the-unit-disk?rq=1

Comment: @DanielFischer, you managed to close this half a minute before I could post an answer. :) The answer may not be that special, but was tailored to this particular question.